# Openfire libs download

Tags: java, jar, openfire

I have downloaded openfire source code, And as mentioned in tutorial it requires coherence.jar, coherence-work.jar, tangosol.jar.

I google'd it but not found any direct downloading link for these jars.

From where I can download these jars. Any link ?

Help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need them at all.  These were required if you wanted to cluster Openfire, but the that has since been replaced by a Hazelcast based solution.

Unless you are setting up a cluster, neither is necessary.

Comment: Thanks for repIy. I have spent 2 days on installing openfire with eclipse but no luck.  I followed https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KlMaBplFbuQ tutorial and ended upto `Unable to compile class for JSP` , `Unable to find a javac compiler;
com.sun.tools.javac.Main is not on the classpath.
Perhaps JAVA_HOME does not point to the JDK`.. Please guide me./